# ITK build Cmake (Gcc compiler) error

Tags: gcc, cmake, itk

Trying to compile ITK software using Cmake on a Linux system. Build fails after 39% complete with following error:

"make[2]: *** [Wrapping/Generators/GccXML/llvm-prefix/src/llvm-stamp/llvm-configure] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Wrapping/Generators/GccXML/CMakeFiles/llvm.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2"

Help?

Also mentions that gcc needs to be version 4.7 or higher, but system has 4.8 installed.

Comment: No more error messages?

Comment: First ran "make" and got to 18% with 
"[ 18%] Built target swig
make: *** [all] Error 2"
And then tried "make install" and got the above error.

Comment: To get more info about error you can try launch `make VERBOSE=1` instead of simple `make`.

Comment: Tried again, got following:
CMake Error at cmake/modules/HandleLLVMOptions.cmake:17 :
  Host GCC version must be at least 4.7!
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also /home/rr128/local/ITK/ITK/bin/Wrapping/Generators/GccXML/llvm-prefix/src/llvm-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also /home/rr128/local/ITK/ITK/bin/Wrapping/Generators/GccXML/llvm-prefix/src/llvm-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make[2]: ** [Wrapping/Generators/GccXML/llvm-prefix/src/llvm-stamp/llvm-configure] Error 1
make[1]: ** [Wrapping/Generators/GccXML/CMakeFiles/llvm.dir/all] Error 2
make: ** [all] Error 2

Comment: It looks like cmake couldn't find gcc.

Comment: Check you CMakeCache.txt file, in the build directory and look for the value of CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER. That will tell you the compiler that CMake is using. You can check the version of that one to make sure it's what you think. It looks like it's trying to use llvm.